# Octave division returning zero

Tags: octave, division

I'm writing a simple octave program that calculate similarity between two images.

The relevant part for this question can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/gBxN7VbP

The function **struct_comp** was supposed to return some number between zero and one. But the command

```
ec = (corr + C) / (dp1 * dp2 + C);
```

is setting ec as 0 even when it should not be zero.

The disp commands are showing the values of all variables involved in this division. The output is:

> C:
>
> 6.5536
>
> dp1
>
> 97.663
>
> dp2
>
> 47.686
>
> corr
>
> -290
>
> (corr + C)
>
> -283
>
> (dp1 * dp2 + C)
>
> 4663.7
>
> (corr + C) / (dp1 * dp2 + C)
>
> 0
>
> Struct comp:
>
> 0

As you can see, the partial values (numerator and denominator) are right, but the division is returning zero.

Somebody knows what is happening here?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

The two images used to generate this output were these:

http://lasca.ic.unicamp.br/~hilder/tux.jpg

http://lasca.ic.unicamp.br/~hilder/monalisa.jpg

But you can use any grayscale image to test, just change the name in the code.

Comment: Without tux.jpg and monalisa.jpg your code does not work here. A smaller code displaying the same problem would be better... Some hints: insert `keyboard` at the end of your "struct_comp" function. This is very handy for debugging purpose. And avoid `global`.

Comment: I edited the question and added the two images I used.  I didn't know this `keyboard` function. I'll search for more information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i replaced the line

```
ec = (corr + C) / (dp1 * dp2 + C);
```

by

```
ec = double(corr + C) / double(dp1 * dp2 + C);
```

and it worked.